# neo4j query an array field that has at least one item in the list

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql, cypher

I want to query a list with a list

```
 p = ['Author-1', Author-2, Author-2]
 a = ['Author-1', Author-2]
 b = ['Author-1', Author-2, Author-3, Author-4]
 c = ['Author-4', Author-5, Author-6, Author-7]
 d = ['Author-5', Author-6, Author-7, Author-8]
```

using p, if one of the lists has at least author1 or author2 return it.

```
WITH p, a, b, c
UNWIND p
WITH DISTINCT p
MATCH (p)
with b as book, collect(g) as genre
WHERE genre in b.genre
return book.isbn, genre
```

my real example returns nothing, the genre is like p in the example above and b.genre is like b,c,d,e
the `WHERE genre in b.genre` is not working properly

```
MATCH (c:Customer { name : "Andrei Balanuta" })-[:CLIENT]-(o:Order)-[ol:ORDERLINE]-(b:Book)
UNWIND b.genre as  g
WITH DISTINCT g
MATCH (b:Book)
with b as book, collect(g) as genre
WHERE genre in b.genre
return book.isbn, genre
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with jQuery, please try and select the correct tags in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actual example, if you have an index on :Book(genre), we can make this an index lookup.

Also we don't need to use variables that are never going to be reused later.

```
MATCH (:Customer { name : "Andrei Balanuta" })-[:CLIENT]-(:Order)-[:ORDERLINE]-(b:Book)
WITH collect(DISTINCT b.genre) as genres
MATCH (b:Book)
WHERE b.genre IN genres
WITH DISTINCT b as book
RETURN book.isbn, book.genre
```

That said, getting all books in all genres matching those of prior ordered books seems a little overkill, maybe a LIMIT or additional filtering would be a good idea.

For your more general example, you can use the any() list predicate

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-any

```
WITH ['Author-1', 'Author-2', 'Author-2'] as p,
 ['Author-1', 'Author-2'] as a,
 ['Author-1', 'Author-2', 'Author-3', 'Author-4'] as b,
 ['Author-4', 'Author-5', 'Author-6', 'Author-7'] as c,
 ['Author-5', 'Author-6', 'Author-7', 'Author-8'] as d,
 ['Author-1', 'Author-2'] as desired
UNWIND [p, a, b, c, d] as list
WITH desired, list
WHERE any(item IN desired WHERE item IN list)
RETURN list
```

Comment: This solution using `ANY` performed faster than the solution I proposed with apoc.coll.intersection when I tested.

Comment: The first query in this solution will only match books that have the exact same genre combination as one previously purchased. If there is partial overlap, they will not be returned, right?

Comment: That depends, in your data model is :Book(genre) a string, or a list of strings?

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of ways you could do this. I think the simplest way would be to search for each genre in the list, and then aggregate the results.

```
MATCH (c:Customer { name : "Andrei Balanuta" })-[:CLIENT]-(o:Order)-[ol:ORDERLINE]-(b:Book)
UNWIND b.genre as  g
WITH DISTINCT g
MATCH (b:Book)
WHERE g in b.genre
RETURN book.isbn, collect(g) AS genre
```

If you have the APOC library installed, you could also use the [apoc.coll.intersection](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.intersection/) function. Something like this might meet your need.

```
MATCH (c:Customer { name : "Andrei Balanuta" })-[:CLIENT]-(o:Order)-[ol:ORDERLINE]-(b:Book)
UNWIND b.genre as  g
WITH collect(distinct g) as customerGenres
MATCH (b2:Book)
WHERE size(apoc.coll.intersection(customerGenres, b2.genre)) > 0
RETURN b2.isbn, b2.genre, customerGenres
```

Both of the queries above are going to include books that the customer has already bought. If you want to avoid that, you could do something like this.

```
MATCH (c:Customer { name : "Andrei Balanuta" })-[:CLIENT]-(o:Order)-[ol:ORDERLINE]-(b:Book)
WITH COLLECT (b) as customerBooks
WITH customerBooks, 
apoc.coll.toSet([book in customerBooks | book.genre]) as customerGenres
MATCH (b2:Book)
WHERE size(apoc.coll.intersection(customerGenres, b2.genre)) > 0
AND NOT b2 in customerBooks
RETURN b2.isbn, b2.genre, customerGenres
```

As a final thought, all of these queries are going to have to search every single book in your database to check the genre properties. If query performance starts to bog down, you might consider making genre into a node instead of a property.